# How to update after echo

Tags: mysql, checkbox, textbox, echo

I have a simple page where users can input their information for a type of request, I then have a separate page that echoes the information the user entered. How can I enter a check box and a text box within each row of my echoed information? The checkbox is for when the request is completed and the text box to enter who completed the request, everything works fine, but I was wondering if this is possible? I'm really just wanting to be pointed in the right direction as I can't seem to find what I'm looking for as of yet. Any assistance is appreciated thanks, for good measure I'll add what I have. Thanks

```
mysql_select_db('mydb');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "First Name:{$row['firstname']}  <br> ".
     "Last Name: {$row['lastname']} <br> ".
     "Model ID: {$row['modelid']} <br> ".
     "System: {$row['system']} <br> ".
     "Department:{$row['department']}  <br> ".
     "Shift: {$row['shift']} <br> ".
     "Comm: {$row['comm']} <br> ".
     "Other: {$row['other']} <br> ".
     "Comments: {$row['comments']} <br> ".
     "Timestamp: {$row['timestamp']} <br> ".
     "TickeID: {$row['TicketID']} <br> ".
     "-----------------------------------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: Just add the two `input` tags to your `echo` and wrap the row in a `form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How can I enter a check box and a text box within each row of my echoed information?"

```
mysql_select_db('mydb');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "First Name:{$row['firstname']}  <br> ".
    "Last Name: {$row['lastname']} <br> ".
    "Model ID: {$row['modelid']} <br> ".
    "System: {$row['system']} <br> ".
    "Department:{$row['department']}  <br> ".
    "Shift: {$row['shift']} <br> ".
    "Comm: {$row['comm']} <br> ".
    "Other: {$row['other']} <br> ".
    "Comments: {$row['comments']} <br> ".
    "Timestamp: {$row['timestamp']} <br> ".
    "TickeID: {$row['TicketID']} <br> ".
    "-----------------------------------------------------------<br>".
    "<form action='target.php' method='POST'>"
        "<input type='checkbox' id='1' value='Option 1'>Option 1<br />".
        "<input type='checkbox' id='2' value='Option 2'>Option 2".
        "<input type='text' id='textBox1' value='' />".
    "</form>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

You should get into the habit of binding strings to variables and using the variables instead of plain strings, It's simply a better practice.

Comment: Ok thanks for the assistance, I'll give it a shot!! So I need to add the checkbox and textbox to my database, however I'm somewhat confused regarding the target.php, how is it being called to update each row without a button?

Comment: No, you are too focused on the database, you can do anything within the while loop, regardless of whether It's part of the database or not. Just init the checkbox and the textbox as variables at the top of the file and let them be a part of the echo. You can echo whatever, you just happen to be fetching data from the database within that loop, you can easily add anything within the loop. The target file that I added there is the file that you will want to post to (You don't need a checkbox or a textbox if you're not going to post it to aything). You can match the boxes with the current id.